# RegEx to get HTML attributes having no value

Tags: regex

For example I have HTML:

```
<html>
    <span href="" />
    <span href="" noname />
    <span noname />
    <span="sss" />
</html>
```

I want to find every attribute which haven't got **=""**. In this example it will be: **"noname"**

My try was:

```
<[A-Za-z]+^={1}.*[A-Za-z]+^\=].*>
```

But without success...

In this case, first attributes **"span"** are OK, so RegEx should not find it. Only these in middle of tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of how the attribute is used without value.

1. It has a space before it
2. It has a space or `/` or `>` after it

Based on above, you can use RegEx [`\s([a-zA-Z]+)[\s/>]`](https://regex101.com/r/qF3aO9/1)

**RegEx Explanation:**

1. `\s`: Matches a space character
2. `([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-]+)`: Match a word starting with alphabet and can contain hyphen `-` symbol and add it in captured group
3. `[\s/>]`: Match either a space, `/`, or `>`

Using JavaScript for Demo purpose:

```js
var str = `<html>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <span class="" noname >Lorem</span>
    <input required />
    <span id="sss" >More Content</span>
    </html>`;

var regex = /\s([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-]+)[\s\/>]/g;

var attributes = str.match(regex);
document.body.innerHTML = attributes;
```

Comment: In this case: content is still captured:

`<a test class="test">content</a>`

Comment: @ghaschel No. Only the `test` attribute is captured. https://regex101.com/r/a3eWKl/1

Comment: @ghaschel is right, but if you add space on content like `<a test class="test"> content </a>`, then the content is still captured.